# Server 2003, XP Clients, DNS issues

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-xp

Im having DNS issues on my network.  My DC is my DNS server 10.76.4.11 and recently I configured  a forwarder to 10.4.36.10.  My workstations are not working because they cannot resolve the domain controller name because of DNS.  an ipconfig /all reveals that they know the IP of the DNS server is 10.76.4.11, but if I nslookup 10.76.4.11 it forwards the request to 10.4.36.10 and goes nowhere.  I have since removed the forwarder, but still any nslookup requests on workstations are going to 10.4.36.10.  If I nslookup 10.76.4.11 on the server it can resolve its name, but for some reason when it receives the same request from workstations it doesnt know what to do.  All the A, CNAME records etc are correct.  DHCP's DNS is set correctly, GPOs are correct (even though they cant refresh cos of this problem!), the servers network adapter has its DNS set to 10.76.4.11.  Just don't know.

I have a reverse lookup zone set, from a workstation I can do an nslookup of the DC using its name, but it seems to go through 10.4.36.10 to resolve it, and it even displays the DCs IP address too!  But still nslookup-ing the DCs IP address alone doesn't work.

The image posting link on here doesnt seem to work for me but I uploaded a screenshot of a nslookup from a workstation here:

[image]

thanks for the help!

Very confused.

Comment: Do you have reverse DNS setup in the 4.76.10.in-addr.arpa domain?

Can you do an nslookup on the DNS name instead of the IP?

Comment: Post the output of nslookup from one of the clients here.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been resolved.

Looks like a crucial DNS suffix was missing/altered and was bringing down the whole system!